# YTPlayerView loads when changing frames/orientation

Tags: ios, swift, youtube

I'm using ***youtube_ios_player_helper*** to load an YouTube video embedded in UIView.
I'm also using AutoLayout to resize the views frame when the orientation is changed. So far, so good.
My issue is that, while the frames are animating (from small size to full screen and back again) the video is loading for a little bit of time. Its not like in the YouTube app, seamlessly resizing itself from the top to full screen and back without loading at all. Even the quality is changing seamlessly, without the activity indicator.

Do you have any idea how to achieve that behaviour?

So, this is how I load the video:

```
videoView.load(withVideoId: videoID, playerVars: ["playsinline": 1 as AnyObject,
                                                     "showinfo": 0 as AnyObject,
                                                     "controls": 0 as AnyObject,
                                                    "autoplay" : 1 as AnyObject,
                                              "modestbranding" : 1 as AnyObject])
```

And I modified this single delegate:

```
func playerViewDidBecomeReady(_ playerView: YTPlayerView) {
    self.fullScreenView.cueVideo(byId: videoID, startSeconds: self.fullScreenView.currentTime(), suggestedQuality: .small)
    playerView.playVideo()
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

YouTube's app will always have smoother playback because they aren't embedding the video.  You won't be able to achieve the same results because you have to embed the videos (or else you violate copyright)...

Comment: Good point. What about XCDYouTubeKit? I tried it and it works perfectly. But I don't know much about it. Can you give me some advice?